# Save readline CLI command history between restarts

Tags: node.js

I am using `readline.createInterface()` to have a REPL interface to my API. Sort of a terminal.

One thing I cannot figure is how to save the command history between restarts? (I am talking about the ability to use UP and DOWN keys to navigate commands entered previously.)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do it directly (using readline). I personnally use the npm package readline-history

https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-history

Comment: The C version of `readline` has a `write_history()` and a `read_history()`, so it's doable.